# Purpose of POM file dependency

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I am trying to understand pom file dependency ,when searching in web I find maven project and unbale to understand maven project .

to use some library in java need to add a dependency in pom file such as imageJ and Tess4J but what if I am working on normal project in netbeans IDE that has no pom file ?

last question : is any project has pom file called maven project ?

I discover that searching in web not enough and need to ask some experience people

Comment: A Maven project has a POM file - it is specifically the configuration for the Maven build tool. If you use “Just a Netbeans project” then, if I remember correctly, you’ll get an Ant project - another build too - which Netbeans uses by default. The advantage of using a build tool (Gradle, Maven, Ant etc) is that your project can be built without an IDE - on a CI server say. So - for example - when you push code you run a GitHub action that compiles and tests your code.

Comment: If you are using Maven (with a POM) then, yes, it can be referred to as "a Maven project" - meaning "a Java project which uses Maven as its build & dependency management tool". (But it could also be referred to as "a NetBeans project" because it is using the NetBeans IDE...) If your project is "an Ant project" (it uses an Ant-based "build.xml" file for building the app), then you do not have dependency management - unless you also use a tool such as Ivy, which integrates with Ant to provide that extra capability.